# List of calculated numbers in TListView - RAD Studio, Delphi

Tags: delphi, tlistbox

Well I have the code that calculates "k" numbers. The "k" is the input from TEdit box. To do it i decided to use the while loop. With each calculation I decrement the "k" so the loop stops when "k" is equal 0. I store each number in the "num" integer variable so it's kind of temporary - "num" is overwritten with each loop route. The clue is I'd like to list the "num" in TListView but I don't know how to do it. I'm the begginer. Any blog, article, YouTube video might be helpful. I don't even know how to ask Google for that haha. Please help me. Finally I'd like to have  the list with "k" entries of "num" numbers. Hope you understand.

Comment: `ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := IntToStr(num)`?

Comment: Don't describe what your code does, show your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this would be to do something like this:

```pascal
procedure TMyForm.FillListView;
var
  i, k, num: Integer;
  item: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
    k := StrToInt(Edit.Text);
    for i := 0 to k-1 do
    begin
      num := ...;
      item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      item.Caption := IntToStr(num);
      // set other properties as needed ...
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, this situation would be better handled using `TListView` in *virtual* mode instead (set its `OwnerData` property to true).  You know from the starting `k` value how many list items you will need to add, so simply set `TListView.Items.Count` to that number, and then in the `TListView.OnData` event you can set the `Caption` (and other properties) of the provided `TListItem` as needed.

```pascal
var
  Nums: array of Integer;

procedure TMyForm.FillListView;
var
  i, k, num: Integer;
begin
  k := StrToInt(Edit.Text);
  if k < 0 then k := 0;
  SetLength(Nums, k);
  for i := 0 to k-1 do
  begin
    num := ...;
    Nums[i] := num;
  end;
  ListView1.Items.Count := k;
  ListView1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(Nums[Item.Index]);
  // set other properties as needed ...
end;
```